# Passing lambda to asio async_wait

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

Why passing a lambda to asio asyn_wait() needs `auto ...` parameter, whereas passing a function doesn't require such a thing (ie just function name would be ok) as in `timer.async_wait( &print );`

```
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer( io_service, boost::posix_time::seconds(5) );
    timer.async_wait( []( auto ... ){   //# ?
        std::cout << timestamp() << ": timer expired\n";
    });

    std::cout << timestamp() << ": calling io_service run\n";

    io_service.run();

    std::cout << timestamp() << ": done\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. It takes any callable that has a boost::system::error_code parameter...

Comment: I overlooked the `print` prototype which indeed has error_code as param. Also it looks a bit intimating with the `auto ...` param

Comment: Where did you get the sample from? You claim "we need auto...", but you don't say why you think that

Comment: @sehe it's from https://youtu.be/rwOv_tw2eA4?t=796
I briefly tried the sample leaving out the original `auto ...` and it didn't compile, and putting it back and it compiles. It was simple but the `auto ...` was a bit misleading at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vinci already stated the callback needs this to look like this:

```cpp
void handler(
  const boost::system::error_code& error // Result of operation.
);
```

The library guarantees that the callback is called exactly once. 
Either when the timer expired or the wait operations was cancelled in the latter case the `error_code` is set to `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.

Source:[boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/async_wait.html)

Comment: I overlooked the print prototype which indeed has error_code as param. Also it looks a bit intimating with the `auto ...` param. Your explanation makes sense.

Comment: I think that the important part is that the parameter is there for a reason and with using auto... you are loosing(not completly but doing it like that is way more complex than writing them out) the ability to check if the operation is complete. There a cases where there are callback parameters that are irrelevant for what you are trying to achieve but to be able to be sure I suggest reading the documentation instead of ignoring them because that is basically what you did here.